# Google Play Services Keeps Stopping, I've tried everything

Tags: google-play-store

I can't get any of my apps to work. I've tried

clearing the data & restarting - works for 10 min then back to square one

force stopping - won't let me

uninstalling updates - it tells me it's unsuccessful

Disabling google play, reenabling, then restarting - still nothing

What else can I do? This is so frustrating.

Comment: try factory reset

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today (just after updating my phone) and eventually found a way to uninstall Google Play Services updates, thanks to the thread in [Google Play Help Forum](https://support.google.com/googleplay/thread/3300947?msgid=9216460):

> I was able to fix the issue today, by uninstalling the Google Play Services updates. Could only do that after making sure 'Find My Phone' was no longer a device administrator. Steps I followed:
>
> 1. Go to Settings -> Lock screen and security -> Other security settings -> Device Administrators
> 2. Uncheck 'Find My Device'
> 3. Go to Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Services
> 4. Tap the vertical ellipsis (3 vertical dots) at the top right -> Uninstall updates
> 5. Go to Settings -> Apps -> Google Play
> 6. Tap the vertical ellipsis (3 vertical dots) at the top right -> Uninstall updates
> 7. Restart phone. At this point the message  "Google Play services keeps stopping" was gone.
> 8. Open one of the Google apps (in my case Google Maps)
> 9. It complains that "Google Play services" is outdated, click the popup to update it again. Problem solved. Really happy to have my phone back ;)

It worked for me (no more error messages, and now I can use again apps such as Google Play Store, Google Maps, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!  I, too, had tried all the other fixes, and I couldn't get this one to work either for a while, until I found the right place to disable "Find my Phone."  For me, it was here:  Settings --> Biometrics and Security --> Other Security Settings --> Device Admin Apps